# I can't install tiktoken on python with pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run some python code which includes some tiktoken calls.

I've tried to install tiktoken for python but i can't. I am trying to install with pip command but i am getting an error about rust. I am wondering if i should install some rust "thing" outside of python or pip.

```
Collecting tiktoken
  Using cached tiktoken-0.3.3.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.26.0 in g:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from tiktoken) (2.28.2)
Collecting regex>=2022.1.18
  Using cached regex-2023.3.23-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (256 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in g:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->tiktoken) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in g:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->tiktoken) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in g:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->tiktoken) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in g:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->tiktoken) (1.26.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: tiktoken
  Building wheel for tiktoken (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for tiktoken (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      copying tiktoken\core.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      copying tiktoken\load.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      copying tiktoken\model.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      copying tiktoken\registry.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      copying tiktoken\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken_ext
      copying tiktoken_ext\openai_public.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken_ext
      running egg_info
      writing tiktoken.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to tiktoken.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to tiktoken.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to tiktoken.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'tiktoken.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'tiktoken.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying tiktoken\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-cpython-38\tiktoken
      running build_ext
      running build_rust
      error: can't find Rust compiler
      
      If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the 
need for a Rust compiler.
     
      To update pip, run:
     
          pip install --upgrade pip
     
      and then retry package installation.
     
      If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tiktoken
Failed to build tiktoken
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tiktoken, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried "pip install tiktoken".

Comment: for Windows py -m pip install tiktoken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip is trying to build the tiktoken library from source and you are missing the Rust compiler. You can either install the Rust compiler on your system, or install tiktoken from a wheel instead of building it from source.

[See this issue in the tiktoken GitHub repo for more help](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/issues/52)